# Prevent angular return repeated string in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this json:

```
[
{
    "month": "Feb",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "status": "Closed"
},
{
    "month": "Feb",
    "title": "Title 2",
    "status": "Delayed"
},
{
    "month": "Feb",
    "title": "Title 3",
    "status": "Open"
},
{
    "month": "Mar",
    "title": "Title 4",
    "status": "Closed"
}
```

]

I'm trying to fill a select box with months:

```
<select id="month" ng-model="monthFilter" ng-options="task.month for task in tasks | filter: monthFilter">
    <option value="">MONTH</option>
</select>
```

I don't know if I'm doing it in the right way but obviously it returns me a list of all arrays' months: `Feb, Feb, Feb, Mar`. How can I make angular return me only `Feb, Mar`?

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: OK, but which `Feb`?

Comment: @Rudy in this case is a filter, it only show one `Feb` and when I select it, it would filter and return me all array with `Feb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-options="task.month for task in tasks | unique:'task.month'"
```

Hope that works for you, or at least leads you in the right direction.

EDIT: Try looking here for what you need: [Angular UI ~ UI.Utils Doc](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, it returns me this error https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=uniqueFilterProvider

Comment: Play around with it or do some more research. This question has been asked more than once here, which is why it was marked as a duplicate before I even answered it.